# HttpPost not working it is showing no error but it is not storing anything in php localhost,

Tags: php, android, json

This code is not working on clicking button it does not show a toast message and do not send data to localhost php server. I am running a android hardware device for debugging, please let me know where the code is incorrect.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText etName,etEmail,etAge;
Button bSubmit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Setup strict mode policy
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //For the name
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
    //For the Age
    etAge  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
    //For the Email
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);

    //setup Onclick Button
    bSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

    bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //Onclick Listener
        InputStream is = null;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           //Storing Values inside the string
            String name = ""+etName.getText().toString();
            String age = ""+etAge.getText().toString();
            String email = ""+etEmail.getText().toString();

            //Setting name pair values
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            //Adding String Variable inside the name value pairs
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", age));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
            //Setting up HTTP Client

            try{

                HttpClient httpClient =  new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:1337/tutorial.php");
                //Passing the name value
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                //Getting the response
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                //Setting up the entity
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();

                        //Display if data entered successfully
                String msg = "Data entered successfully";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Setting up the content inside an input stream

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
               Log.e("ClientProtocol","Log_tag");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e("Log tag","IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

(Edit)
This is the php file code I am using Xampp (localhost:1337) 
    $name=isset($_POST['name'];
       $age=isset($_POST['age']);
       $email=isset($_POST['email']);

```
   mysql_query("insert into newtable(name,age,email) values('{$name}','{$age}','{$email}')");
```

Comment: GCM: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: @Yazan: What is the relation between his question and GCM? How does your question help?

Comment: <?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root' , '');
mysql_select_db("newdatabase",$con)
or 
die("Unable to connect to database");

$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=isset($_POST['age']);
$email=isset($_POST['email']);


$success=mysql_query("insert into newtable(name,age,email) values('{$name}','{$age}','{$email}')");
    

?>

Comment: @BalaVishnu why do u think i have +2 on my comment? is it because it was FAR from the OP question? \check the question revision it was different question, the OP changed the entire question by editing it, that's really BAD practice : rev-link http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27764787/revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in this, let me list one by one.

1. As per your description you have mentioned that your running in localhost PHP Server(I assume its WAMP Server),  and you have also mentioned that you are running the app in a real hardware device. If your running in real device, then localhost is of no use. You need your own server(you can find a lot of free hosting websites). If you prefer to use only WAMP, then test it in an Emulator.
2. Network operations performed in main thread which is not allowed(thats why you have used Strict Mode - Remove those two lines). learn to use Async Task for network operations.

This would be a good reference for you

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: does using Xampp will solve the problem? I am using Xampp server and putting php file in htdocs folder.

Comment: Are you testing in a device or emulator?

Comment: I am testing it on emulator as in localhost I write localhost:1337 to display php result therefore I used it :1337 in httppost.

Comment: loose the port, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone error was somewhere in the port plus in php POST function now its working perfect.